# What improvements can I make to this table filtering jQuery Plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This plugin is meant to filter through a table based on column header text that matches options given to it. 
check it out here: [Filter Table Plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/CEZx7/1/)

Plugin code below for reference:

```
//framework from http://jqueryboilerplate.com/
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    var pluginName = "filterTable",
        defaults = {
        };
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;

        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

        init: function () {

            $el = $(this.element);
            $table = $('#' + $el.data('filtertable'));
            var filterColumnNames = ($el.attr('data-filtercolumns')).split(',');
            var filterColumns = new Array();
            var altRowCSS = $el.data('filteralternatingcss');

            //get the column index of the column we'll be filtering on
            $table.find('th').each(function (i) {
                for (j in filterColumnNames) {
                    if ($(this).text().trim() == filterColumnNames[j]) {
                        filterColumns.push(i + 1);
                    }
                }
            });

            $el.keyup(function () {
                var query = $(this).val();
                var numDisplayed = 0;
                //remove any no result warnings
                $table.find('#noResultsRow').remove();
                //hide all rows
                $table.find('tr').removeClass(altRowCSS).hide();
                //show the header row
                $table.find('tr:first').show();
                for (i in filterColumns) {
                    $table.find('tr td:nth-child(' + filterColumns[i] + ')').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                            $(this).parent().show();
                            numDisplayed++;
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (numDisplayed == 0) {
                    $tr = $('<tr>');
                    $tr.attr('id', 'noResultsRow');
                    $td = $('<td>').attr('colspan', $table.children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length);
                    $td.html('No results for filter "' + query + '."');
                    $td.css({ textAlign: 'center' });
                    $tr.append($td);
                    $table.children('tbody').append($tr);
                }
                $table.find('tr:visible :odd').addClass(altRowCSS);
            });
            $el.keyup();
        },
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Any improvements I can make?

Comment: Forgot to mention one thing I might add is matching against whole words only -  instead of 'ter' matching filter and terminal, it would only match terminal.

Comment: Did you mean you're only matching at the start of the word? Neither `terminal` or `filter` are whole word matches of `ter`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have:

   ```
   this._defaults = defaults;
   ```

   This is redundant as the declaration :

   ```
   var pluginName = "filterTable",
       defaults = {
       };
   ```

   Can be accessed anywhere in your plugin.
2. Declare all variables that you use. This is a really good practice to have change lines like:

   ```
    $el = $(this.element);
    $table = $('#' + $el.data('filtertable'));
   ```

   to:

   ```
   var $el = $(this.element);
   var $table = $('#' + $el.data('filtertable'));
   ```

   JavaScript will let you use them without but you'll run into issues otherwise.
3. Variables need meaningful names so their lives don't seem meaningless and they despair.

   > [Invective! Verb your expletive nouns!](http://thecodelesscode.com/case/34)

   ```
   $table.find('th').each(function (i)
   {
       for (j in filterColumnNames)
       {
           if ($(this).text().trim() == filterColumnNames[j])
           {
                filterColumns.push(i + 1);
           }
       }
    });
   ```

   What is `i`? index? columnIndex?
   What is `j`? currentColumnName?